# How to send payload to temporal workflow from golang testcases/function

Tags: go, testing, workflow

Is there any way to test workflow without mocking up.
My requirement is like, sending the payload to workflow and capturing the actual result for assertion.

The workflow looks as below
func (w Exampleworkflow) CreateWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context, messageType string, payloadBytes []byte) error {

```
err = workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, w.CheckCustomer, payload.CustId).Get(ctx, &customerFound)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("customer does not exists", "Error:", err)
        updates.AddErrorEventWithDetail(ctx, "The workflow interrupted with an error", nil)
        return err
    }
```

A solution to invoke the workflow from go test suite by posting the payload.

Comment: func (w Exampleworkflow) CreateWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context, messageType string, payloadBytes []byte) error {
...........
err = workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, w.CheckCustomer, payload.CustId).Get(ctx, &customerFound)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("customer does not exists", "Error:", err)
        updates.AddErrorEventWithDetail(ctx, "The workflow interrupted with an error", nil)
        return err
    }
..............
}

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you clarify a little bit?

Comment: @IvanPesenti - Im very new to go & temporal, so not sure that my questions makes any sense. 1. Above is my example workflow and how it can be tested without any mock-up values. 2. How to pass the payload to this func 3. Will the go testcase func can return any value?